# Obtainig illegible characters from uCanAccess result set

Tags: java, database, character-encoding, resultset, ucanaccess

I'm querying an old Access 97 database with Spanish characters `ñ á é í ó ú`. I can read the characters fine using access so I'm assuming it uses `ISO-8859-1` however I am not able to convert them to UTF-8.

Not sure if my problem has to do with my connection:

```
public static Connection baseAccess(String base) {
    try {
        java.util.Properties propiedades = new java.util.Properties();
        propiedades.put("charSet", "ISO-8859-1");
        return DriverManager.getConnection(String.format("jdbc:ucanaccess://%s", base),propiedades);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {}
}
```

Or with my parsing of the String:

```
try (ResultSet rs = UtileriaDb.baseAccess(contabilidad).createStatement().executeQuery(sql);){
    while(rs.next()){
        String fromAccess = rs.getString(1);
        System.out.println(fromAccess);
        String transformed = new String(fromAccess.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8");
        System.out.println(transformed);
    }
} catch (Exception ex) { }
```

So when I expect:

> Año Café

I get:

> A�o Caf�
>
> A?o Caf?

Tried by getting the byte content from the result set by doing: `byte[] fromAccess = rs.getBytes(1);` but I got an exception

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.4 incompatible data type in conversion: from SQL type VARCHAR to [B, value: myText
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessResultSet.getBytes(UcanaccessResultSet.java:339)
```

So that's a dead end. Is there maybe another way to go about it?

Comment: Are you running this on a CLI or an IDE? What is the type of `rs`?

Comment: the type is `java.sql.ResultSet` just updated the question snippet I am writing the `transformed` String into a mySql table with `default charset=latin1` and the non ascii values are stored as `?` as well
The ouput is from netbeans terminal, will try with bash and cmd as well

Comment: I think the problem is `rs.getString(1);` I'd use `byte[] bytes = rs.getBytes(1)` instead and then `transformed = new String(bytes, 'ISO-8859-1');`

Comment: Great idea!, however I get an `SQLException` `incompatible data type in conversion: from SQL type VARCHAR to [B, value: myText` . I don't think ucanaccess supports it. Stack trace says is at `net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessResultSet.getBytes(UcanaccessResultSet.java:339)`

Comment: Next logical step would be your assumption "I'm assuming it uses `ISO-8859-1`" :)

Comment: Yes, tought so as well, not sure if access 97 used any other encoding to be honest, I also have my doubts about how I'm setting the `charSet` property, it might be `charset` instead of `charSet` and `ISO 8859-1` instead of `ISO-8859-1`. Also I'm not sure thats actually doing anything to configure the `DriverManager`, hope Gord Thompson could shed more light about it but will continue to test in the meantime

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208681/discussion-between-scratte-and-leedmx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Scratte correctly pointed out, `rs.getString(1)` was returning a String that already contained replacement characters. Thanks for his help in pointing me towards [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59714917/charset-for-ms-access-97-db-using-ucanaccess) and [this discussion](https://sourceforge.net/p/ucanaccess/discussion/help/thread/383274d6/)

I ended up implementing a ucanaccess `JackcessOpenerInterface` and worked wonderfully

```
package com.company.somepackage;

import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.Database;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.DatabaseBuilder;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import net.ucanaccess.jdbc.JackcessOpenerInterface;

public class CharsetOpener implements JackcessOpenerInterface {
    public Database open(File f, String pwd) throws IOException {
        DatabaseBuilder db = new DatabaseBuilder(f);
        db.setCharset(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
        try {
            db.setReadOnly(false);
            return db.open();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            db.setReadOnly(true);
            return db.open();
        }
   }
}
```

And for the implementation in my Connection generator:

```
public static Connection baseAccess(String base) {
    try {
        java.util.Properties propiedades = new java.util.Properties();
        propiedades.put("jackcessOpener", "com.company.somepackage.CharsetOpener");
        return DriverManager.getConnection(String.format("jdbc:ucanaccess://%s", base),propiedades);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {}
}
```

Notice that the actual property is `jackcessOpener` and must point to a fully qualified class name.